# Pass dynamic value to higher order component

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

In my code I have to use the same lines of code at different places. So i thought that's the right time to put this code into a kind of base class. I've read about [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which seems to be the way to go and following some examples i ended up with the following code, which is not working. I've tried something around but was not able to get it work.

My HOC:

```
export interface HocProps {
    DynamicId: string
}

const withDiv = (hocProps) => (BaseComponent) => {
    return class extend React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div id={ hocProps.DynamicId }>
                    <BaseComponent />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withDiv;
```

A component to be wrapped by the div:

```js
import withDiv from './MyHoc';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h3>Some content here</h3>
        );
    }
}

export default withDiv({ DynamicId: <dynamic value> })(MyComponent);
```

Another component, that uses MyComponent:

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ... Some content here ...
                <MyComponent DynamicId={ 'id123' } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass an id to  in OtherComponent. Then in MyComponent this id has to be passed to the HOC as , which is not working. I only can pass static values to the HOC.

I'm new to react and I think i've made same mistake(s).

So my question is: What am i doing wrong and how is it done right?
Maybe there is another/better way for this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I would expect this result:

```
<div>
    ... Some content here ...
    <div id='id123'>
        <h3>Some content here</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you passing the dynamic id in your `OtherComponent`?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the code but I'm not sure, whether this would work or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can use HOCs according to your implementation. 
I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-wiles-k9m8h), which will help you understand how to use HOCs.

One way is to extract your props out `const hocWrapper = Component => props => { // return NewComponent and call it too }`. Here you have to call your component while returning.

Other way is to destructure or use the props inside hocWrappers. `const hocWrapper = Component => { // return NewComponent, you will receive props inside the newComponent and do what you wish}`

Comment: Thanks you. Handling the props in the right way did the trick. This confused me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const withDiv = (BaseComponent) => {
    class CompWithDiv extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div id={this.props.DynamicId}>
                    <BaseComponent />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    return CompWithDiv ;
}

export default withDiv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you pass the dynamic values and whats wrong with it. but, you can just create your component like

```
export interface MyCustomProps {
    customProp: string;
}

export interface MyCustomState {
    something: string;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyCustomProps, MyCustomState>{
  render(){<div>
    ... Some content here ...
    <div>{this.props.customProp}</div>
  </div>}
}
export default MyComponent
```

and use it in another component like

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            ... Some content here ...
            <MyComponent customProp={someDynamicStringValues}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and you can do it recursively

Comment: I've added the expected result to my post. I'm not sure if your solution is correct. Where is the <h3> tag? I like to reuse the code of my hoc. So when i have another component MyComponent2 which renders <h2> instead of <h3> it should be wrapped in the <div id='...'> tag from the hoc, too.

Comment: i've tried to write a general answer, you can use props where ever and how ever you want. When you look at the rendered html from browser you will see your expected answer actually.